# Ubuntu to Kubuntu - how to access existing apps?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, snap, plasma

I recently installed KDE Plasma + Kubuntu, but am keeping the old Gnome Ubuntu for now.

In the Gnome desktop I would open various apps by clicking the "Win" key and start typing the name of the app.

In the Plasma desktop I can do this for most apps, but this doesn't work for apps that were installed via `snap` on Gnome. The only results I get are for the app's folder.

(I know I can type the name of the snap apps in the terminal, but that isn't what I am looking for...)

Comment: sorry, I had some issues booting up and ended up scrapping the KDE desktop... Thanks for taking a look anyway.